# Coronavirus origin could be bat, why this happen while people have been eating bats for centuries?

Tags: virology, vector

Sorry for my lack of understanding, Why now, when people been eating bats for centuries? If bats are simply a vector, where does that virus come from?

Comment: Please see the meta discussion and contribute. I thoroughly disagree that biology.SE doesn't have the expertise to answer questions about biological concepts and disease mechanisms as they relate to virology. They are, in fact, explicitly [on topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question's problems are related to the lack of prior research. Address that issue and I will vote to re-open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bats are reservoirs of many important human pathogens, some are emerging infections (e.g., 2019-NCoV, the coronavirus in the news recently), and some are not (e.g., rabies).

Contact between humans and bats is certainly not a new phenomena, but there is more required for an *emerging* infection than a reservoir and a new host. There must be some bridge that allows a virus to cross a previously effective species barrier. For SARS, there was an intervening amplifying host, the palm civet.  We've now had long enough to study the molecular biology, so this is now [quite well described](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3840050/):

> Once SARS-CoV had jumped from bats to civets, it underwent further mutations in civets. The first K479N mutation allowed SARS-CoV to jump from civets to humans and the second S487T mutation allowed SARS-CoV to transmit from human to human, leading to the severe SARS outbreak in 2002–2003.

It may be useful to understand that, as they are RNA viruses, [coronaviridae have a high error rate](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK8439/), increasing the rate of mutation. Additionally, making a species jump may allow for novel recombination.

Comment: I think you could expand a bit on the lack of stability in viral populations.

Comment: @BryanKrause done. Feel free to expand further if you'd like.

Comment: The four endemic human coronaviruses are all bat-origin coronaviruses that have jumped into humans in the past 100 years, so the premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: @iayork that's fascinating. For some reason I was remembering bovine coronavirus, rather than bat as a source for human coronaviruses.

Comment: A more recent study suggests that two of them may have passed through livestock first (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/29551135/) and may or may not have started in rodents